# Recargar div de la ventana padre con Javascript desde una ventana emergente

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

Tengo una página (*ventana padre*) que abre una ventana emergente (*hija*) con *JavaScript*, y al pulsar un botón desde la ventana hija, se cierra, y necesito que se actualice un `div` de la ventana padre.

He probado con `parent.location.reload` pero me recarga toda la página y no quiero eso, quiero actualizar solo un determinado elemento de la pantalla.

También he probado hacer `document.getElementById.reload` pero tampoco funciona. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto con *JavaScript*?

El valor que hay que actualizar, se actualiza en *Java* mediante un `action` que tiene el botón. Lo único que necesito es que se actualice esa parte de la página para mostrar ese valor.

Comment: que es lo qué actualizas? estas seguro que se realiza la actualización de la información? podrías poner código?.

Comment: @Luis lo que quiero actualizar es el texto asociado a este botón : (ventana padre)
 <td width="300px" class="I"> 
<a4j:commandButton id="boton" value="#{javaBean.texto}" styleClass="estilo"> </a4j:commandButton> </td> Y en la ventana hija, asociado a otro botón tengo esta función javascript window.opener.document.getElementById('boton').location.relo‌​ad() que lo que quiero es que coja por el id boton y le haga un reload para que actualice el texto (que se actualiza en java) pero no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los elementos HTML no tienen atributo location ni menos soportan que los recargues usando `location.reload` por lo que ahora debieras estar recibiendo el error

```
Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined
```

Lo que podrías probar es gatillar el evento click en el botón de la ventana padre:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('boton').click()
```

Esto **suponiendo que el click en el botón** provoque justamente que se refresque el div que lo contiene.

De lo contrario, primero tienes que darle a la página principal alguna manera de recargar parcialmente su contenido (via ajax por ejemplo) para poder gatillar esa misma acción desde una ventana hija.

Comment: Ha funcionado a la perfección, la respuesta fue concisa y muy bien explicada. Muchísimas gracias!